# How can I get the data out of a table using Semantic UI React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to learn React and using React Semantic UI. I've got a table and I can't figure out how to get the data out of it. I'd like to get the id of the user when the checkbox is clicked but I can't find any example of how to do so (maybe this is just a super basic question and I'm overlooking something). I've tried to get the data on the row click initially, the table is like this

```
    <Table collapsing compact celled definition>
     <Table.Header>
       <Table.Row>
         <Table.HeaderCell />
         <Table.HeaderCell>First Name</Table.HeaderCell>
         <Table.HeaderCell>Last Name</Table.HeaderCell>
       </Table.Row>
     </Table.Header>

     <Table.Body>
       {students.map(student => <Table.Row key={student.student_id} onClick = {handleRowClick}>
         <Table.Cell collapsing>
           <Checkbox />
         </Table.Cell>
         <Table.Cell
           children = {student.fname}>
         </Table.Cell>
         <Table.Cell
           children = {student.lname}>
         </Table.Cell>
       </Table.Row>)}
     </Table.Body>
    </Table>
```

And the row click function is where I'm flailing. I've tried various things but I generally just get undefined.

```
      handleRowClick = (student) => {console.log(this.props.children);}
```

I found this question which seems the same ([How to get data from table row click using Semantic's React Table Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223937/how-to-get-data-from-table-row-click-using-semantics-react-table-component)) but I can't get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily by using `bind`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

In your map function, you have access to `student`, so you can bind it to your `onClick` function like this:

```js
{students.map(
    student => <Table.Row onClick={handleRowClick.bind(this, student)}/>
)}
```

Then you can access `student` as the first parameter of your function:

```js
handleRowClick = (student) => console.log(student)
```

Any other parameters will be filled in after `student` if you need them.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!